# File read and store it in array spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a delimiter file like this.

```
 2:-31:20063:28:0:1496745908:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-41:20063:28:0:1496745909:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-35:20063:28:0:1496745910:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-44:20063:28:0:1496745911:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-41:20063:28:0:1496745912:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3 
 2:-51:20063:28:0:1496745913:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-52:20063:28:0:1496745914:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
 2:-61:20063:28:0:1496745915:3879:0:0:0:0:6:4:3
```

I want to read this file and store it in array. I want to access each and every column for aggregation purpose. I tried like this.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Proximity Filter").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val input = sc.textFile("/home/arun/Desktop/part-r-00000")
val wordCount = input.flatMap(line => line.split(":"))
val input1 = wordCount.take(0)
System.out.print(input1)  
}
```

Comment: so are you getting any errors? what is the question about?

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using RDD? I would imagine a better solution would be to use dataframe or dataset semantics which would allow you to use the dataframereader with csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `flatMap` to `map` and you should be fine as

```
val wordCount = input.map(line => line.split(":"))
wordCount.foreach(array => println(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3), array(4), array(5), array(6), array(7), array(8), array(9), array(10), array(11), array(12)))
```

you should have output as

```
( 2,-31,20063,28,0,1496745908,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-41,20063,28,0,1496745909,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-35,20063,28,0,1496745910,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-44,20063,28,0,1496745911,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-41,20063,28,0,1496745912,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-51,20063,28,0,1496745913,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-52,20063,28,0,1496745914,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
( 2,-61,20063,28,0,1496745915,3879,0,0,0,0,6,4)
```

changing your `flatMap` to `map` would generate you with rdd of string array

```
scala> val wordCount = input.map(line => line.split(":"))
wordCount: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:26
```

Whereas using `flatMap` would give your rdd of strings

```
scala> val wordCount = input.flatMap(line => line.split(":"))
wordCount: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at flatMap at <console>:26
```